# Cómo usar JQuery.print.js

Tags: jquery

estoy intentando usar el pluggin `JQuery.print` para imprimir una determinda área de la vista (como alternativa a un reporte) pero una vez que incluyo el `Jquery.print.js` por debajo de la inclusión de `jquery.js` en la página, veo que me salta el siguiente error en la consola del navegador al cargar la página.

```
SyntaxError: in strict mode code, functions may be declared only at top level or immediately within another function
```

*jQuery.print.js en la línea 34*
Es un error en el fichero de la librería, y por tanto el código para emplearla no funciona:

```
$('.lnkImprimir').on('click', function(e))
{
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#divImprimir').print();
}
```

alguien que la haya usado, y me pueda explicar.

Comment: Que versión de jQuery y jQuery.print usas?

Comment: Uso JQuery 2.2.0 y la versión de JQuery.print 1.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas, el error del que e queja `SyntaxError: in strict mode code, functions may be declared only at top level or immediately within another function` es porque estás en modo estricto `strict mode`.
Quita la línea `"use strict"` en tu código y debería arreglar-se.

Con este modo el compilador no te deja pasar según que cosas, va muy bien usar-lo ya que jQuery es muy "libre".

[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

Comment: gracias !!! resuelto de esta manera, le quité la línea "use strict" y funciona de las mil maravillas. Qué problemas pudieran darse al quitar esa línea, o acaso en versiones recientes de navegadores funcionaría sin tener que quitar ese código.